# `ping -c` in Windows: output error `Bad value for option -c.`

Tags: windows, networking, ping, command-line-arguments

I am learning `ping` utility in Windows 10 and when I try to run command in shell:

```
ping -c 3 example.com
```

I get the result:

```
Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges.
```

After executing from the administrator I get:

```
Bad value for option -c.
```

---

The command reference (`ping /?`) says about this argument:

- `[-c compartment]` - Routing compartment identifier.

What does that mean? What values can this argument take?

However, `-c` is not mentioned on the [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/ping)!

---

I also tried to use this command like this: `ping -c google.com 8.8.8.8`. Output:

```
Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=127ms TTL=58
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=58
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=58
Reply from 8.8.8.8: bytes=32 time=57ms TTL=58

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 57ms, Maximum = 127ms, Average = 74ms
```

There was no error, but the result is the same as the command `ping 8.8.8.8`

---

So, how do I use `ping -c` correctly in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you're using the `-c` parameter to stand for the
count of ping requests. Under Windows the parameter is
(default is `3`):

```
-n count       Number of echo requests to send.
```

You may see all the parameters by using the command `ping /?`.

For the question about compartments :

Compartments are just relics of the earlier plans of supporting routing
compartments in Windows Vista.
Routing compartments were not re-introduced in later versions of Windows.

Some of the Windows commands still support parameters for compartments,
dating from that partial implementation that was never finished,
such as `-c` on `ping`, but these produce either errors or unusable
information:

```
Ipconfig /allcompartments
Netsh interface ipv4 show compartments
Netsh interface ipv4 set compartment…
```